# Programming iOS button to do action on first tap then segue on second tap

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue, ibaction

I am building a 3rd party iOS app. As part of my main view controller, I give the user the option to press a button to link directly to the iOS keyboard settings so that they can enable my keyboard. When they return back to the app, it takes them to the next view where they can test the keyboard on an empty text field.

When the user hits the enable keyboard button on the app, I invoke an IBAction to link them to the settings app as such:

```
@IBAction func enableKeyboard(_ sender: Any) {
        let settingsUrl = URL(string: "\(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)")!
        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl)
    }
```

However, I concurrently have a segue to my `textViewController` so that when the user returns to the app from settings, they immediately go to the textViewController.

[image]

How would I be able to program my button so that the first tap takes them to settings, they return to the main view controller, and then the second tap takes them to the next view?

Comment: Store a bool within the controller, set it on the first button tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip the selected state of the button, and then test this when deciding what to do.

```
@IBAction func touchUpInside(button: UIButton) {
    if !button.isSelected {
        button.isSelected = true
        // Now open settings
    } else {
       // Perform segue
    }
}
```

The button class is designed to keep track of its own state, so I believe this is preferable to having a variable keep track of the click in your view controller where only 2 states are required.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some state to your controller.
It will be useful not only for 2 states ('to  open settings' and 'to open next view'), you will be able to manage more states.

You can add state variable in your controller:

```
enum ControllerState {
    case needSettings, needNext
}
private var state: ControllerState = .needSettings

@IBAction func yourButtonHandler(sender: UIButton) {
    switch state {
    case .needSettings:
        state = .needNext
        // Open settings
    case .needNext:
        // Open next view controller
    }
}
```